# Iperf results on Bandwidth and Transfer do not make sense

Tags: iperf

I'm having trouble understanding why iperf is behaving the way it is. I'm just trying to send UDP traffic from a Raspberry Pi to my Computer.

This is what it looks like on the **Client Side**:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iperf -c 192.168.0.5 -t 10 -i 1 -u -b 10000m
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.0.5, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 1.18 us (kalman adjust)
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.0.200 port 51303 connected with 192.168.0.5 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  11.5 MBytes  96.3 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.3 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  11.3 MBytes  95.2 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  11.3 MBytes  95.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  11.3 MBytes  94.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   114 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 2 datagrams
[  3] Server Report:
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   114 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec   0.201 ms    0/81153 (0%)
```

---

Now this is what it looks like on the **Server Side**:

```
Comp-Name:Directory username$ iperf -s -i 1 -u
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  768 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.0.5 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.200 port 51303
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.6 Mbits/sec   0.136 ms    0/ 8128 (0%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec   0.120 ms    0/ 8113 (0%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec   0.149 ms    0/ 8124 (0%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec   0.270 ms    0/ 8122 (0%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec   0.255 ms    0/ 8119 (0%)
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.5 Mbits/sec   0.272 ms    0/ 8124 (0%)
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec   0.390 ms    0/ 8109 (0%)
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  11.3 MBytes  95.0 Mbits/sec   0.202 ms    0/ 8079 (0%)
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  11.3 MBytes  94.9 Mbits/sec   0.273 ms    0/ 8070 (0%)
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  11.4 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec   0.273 ms    0/ 8113 (0%)
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   114 MBytes  95.4 Mbits/sec   0.202 ms    0/81153 (0%)
```

If I am trying to push 10,000 Mbps of data, why are the **Bandwidth (Mbits/sec)** and **Transfer (MBytes)** capping themselves at ~95 and ~11.4?

Shouldn't iperf try to push the traffic and show loss after capping instead? Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks,
moodieftw

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the processing time and protocol overhead. This looks pretty normal for a 100 Mbps connection.

Comment: Which model is you raspberry pi?

Comment: Because you told the test to run for 10s and the interface is physically 100Mbps. No amount of commandline switches will turn a 100M interface into a 10G interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 1,2 and zero have a 100Mb/s network interface card, so this is likely what caps the traffic.
(the raspberry pi 3 has a gigabit Ethernet interface but it is connected to the processor through USB 2, so is limited to USB 2 speed at 300Mb/s).

The reported Transfer and bandwidth are consistent with a 100Mb/s connection. As hinted by @Ron Maupin in comment, there are overhead (headers and processing) that cause the usable bandwidth to be slightly less than the interface speed.

> Shouldn't iperf try to push the traffic and show loss after capping
>   instead?

No, this is not how it works. The reported bandwidth is what is actually sent.

Answer (score 0):

The client socket writes are blocking or getting [EAGAIN or ENOBUFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) because the window is small.  Increase it with -w and then the kernel will drop after the write but before the transmit. Also, the output per -e might be helpful. This won't impact the end/end measurement per the 100Mb/s link but may cause the client to exceed that. This is due to UDP being connectionless and such that the traffic will be dropped by the client's kernel.

Comment: Forgot to say that yes the iperf client with UDP should exceed the link phy rate and lose packets. What version are you using? Iperf -v will give that